# Lyx's update button does not work

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX Version 2.3.6.1 on windows 10.

My default PDF viewer is Adobe Acrobat reader DC.

The view button works as expected, it opens adobe reader and shows the pdf.

However, After making changes and clicking update, nothing happens .... the changes are not shown in adobe reader....

Any way to fix this  ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Adobe Reader locks the .pdf. Use SumatraPDF instead.

Comment: Is there a way to make adobe reader not lock the .pdf ?

Comment: Any alternatives to sumatraPDF ?

Comment: For Adobe Reader, unfortunately, I don't use LyX. I know that with the WinEdt editor, you can use a macro script to unlock the .pdf before recompiling, but this is very specific to this editor. . I don't know alternatives to SumatraPDF that don't lock the .pdf. You must know that it is a small executable, which is very fast and is specially designed for LaTeX. I guess you could use it with LyX without making it you default pdf viewer, and further, it has among its menus ‘Open with Acrobat Reader’.

Comment: The problem with SumatraPDF is that the quality of the pdf rendered by it is very poor...AADC is superior to SumatraPDF in that regard...